# How to call a method and pass parameter in java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

The code is listed below. So I expected the output to be {2 4 6 8 10}, however, when I test it, the result is {1 2 3 4 5}. I am confused now, can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

```
public class practice{ 
    public void doubler(int[] a)
    {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
        {
            b[i] = 2*a[i];
        }
        a = b;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int[]c = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Practice w = new Practice();
        w.doubler(c);
        for(int count = 0; count<c.length; count++)
        {
            System.out.print(c[count] + " ");
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is it even allowing you to do `int[] s = w.doubler(c);`  ..... is my question

Comment: `a` in `doubler` is a different variable from `c` in `main`.

Comment: You will be surprised, but it is duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Lashane Thank you, this is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is helpful for you,

```
public class practice{ 
    public int[] doubler(int[] a)
    {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
        {
            b[i] = 2*a[i];
        }
        return b;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int[]c = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Practice w = new Practice();
        int[] s=w.doubler(c);
        for(int count = 0; count<s.length; count++)
        {
            System.out.print(s[count] + " ");
        }
    } 
}
```

I your case, you didn't return multiplied array to `int[] s`.

Comment: I did it but it still gives me the same output...(1 2 3 4 5)

Comment: Did you loop output for int[] s like this , System.out.print(s[count] + " ");

Comment: @CherylLiang literally copy and paste his code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since double is void method following doesnt work

```
int[] s=w.doubler(c);
```

because it would be similar as

```
int[] s= void; // wrong
```

change the return type of the method

```
public int[] doubler(int[] a)
```

and return the array b as soon as the method is done with the job

Answer (score 0):

Change method `doubler` to :

```
public int[] doubler(int[] a)
    {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
        {
            b[i] = 2*a[i];
        }
        return b;
    }
```

This will give you new array `b`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did it but it still prints out the original c array. I feel like there is something wrong with my main method.

Comment: You have to do `c = w.doubler(c);` in main method.